# Migration spring app from JBoss 7.1 to Wildfly

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, migration, wildfly

I have an application on production using Spring 4 MVC, Spring Data and Spring Security running on JBoss 7.1, everythink works fine.

Now I want to migrate this application to running on Wildfly with Java 8. When my application is deploying this error appears:

```
JBAS016069: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named sgn-core in deployment sgn-web.war
```

I put JPA logs on TRACE and Wildfly is dysplaing this:

```
6:38:41,835 TRACE [org.jboss.as.jpa.messages] (weld-worker-2) pu search for name 'sgn-core' inside of sgn-web.war

16:38:41,841 TRACE [org.jboss.as.jpa.messages] (weld-worker-2) pu findWithinDeployment searching for sgn-core

16:38:41,842 TRACE [org.jboss.as.jpa.messages] (weld-worker-2) pu findWithinDeployment skipping empty pu holder for sgn-core

...

16:38:41,912 TRACE [org.jboss.as.jpa.messages] (weld-worker-2) findWithinLibraryJar checking for 'sgn-core' found no persistence units

...
```

But my application is the same, and didn't change anythink.

Here is the full [server.log](http://snipt.org/QhKg7)

sgn-core is the name of my persistence-unit.

Everythink works well on JBoss 7.1 on production but now on Wildfly

Please could someone help me?

Comment: I think this requires more information about your setup. Can you post your persistence.xml, ... Did you include a beans.xml? What is sgn-core and where/how is it defined and bound?

Comment: Hi,

Now the information is it ok?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Mine turned out to be that I had miss-spelled the persistence.xml file.